# graph automorphism translating each finite set

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

Consider the following well-known definition: An automorphism $g$ (action on vertices) of a connected (not necessarily locally finite) infinite graph is called *translation* if $g \cdot F \neq F$ for any *finite*, non-empty set $F$ (of vertices).

I came across the following statement (Lemma 1.1 in Jung, *Some results on ends and automorphisms of graphs*):

> For any translation $g$ of a connected graph $X$ and any finite set $F$ there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $g^i \cdot F \cap g^j \cdot F = \emptyset$, whenever $|j - i| \geq n$

It suffices to show that there is an integer $n > 0$ such that $g^i \cdot F \cap F = \emptyset$ whenever $i \geq n$. This should follow from the fact that for every vertex $x$ the elements $g^i \cdot x$ are all distinct.

It is easy to show the existence of $n$ such that $g^n \cdot F \cap F = \emptyset$, however I somehow got stuck to show this for **every $i \geq n$**. I'm pretty sure that I just overlooked something trivial but nonetheless any help would be very appreciated!

**EDIT 1:** The point is that the orbit of $x \in VX$ under $g$, $Orb_g(x) := \{g^n \cdot x \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$, is infinite for *every* $x$. If it would finite for some $x$ then this finite orbit would be a finite set fixed by $g$ which is forbidden.

**EDIT 2:** Hagen von Eitzen solved the question (big thanks to him). However I would still be interested in probably different solutions.

Comment: Are we assuming the graph is infinite ?

Comment: yes, infinitely many vertices and *not* necessarily locally finite (i.e. vertices can have infinitely many incident edges). An automorphism of a finite graph cannot be a translation since it would fix the (finite) vertex set of the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there are infinitely many $k\in\mathbb N$ with $g^kF\cap F\ne \emptyset$, i.e., triples $(k,a,b)\in\mathbb N\times F\times F$ with $g^ka=b$. As $F$ is finite, some pair $(a,b)$ must occur infinitely often. But if $g^{k_0}a=g^{k_1}a=b$ with $k_0<k_1$, then the finite set $\{g^{k_0}a,\ldots,g^{k_1-1}a\}$ is $g$-invariant.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you very much!!

Comment: Do you think the same statement is true if we interchange *finite* with *bounded* throughout the whole OP?